# Display output from another python script in jupyter notebook

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I run a loop in my jupyter notebook that references another python file using the execfile command.
 I want to be able to see all the various prints and outputs from the file I call from execfile.   However, I don't see any of the pandas dataframe printouts.  E.g. if I just say  'df' I don't see the output of the table of the dataframe.  However, I will see 'print 5'.

Can someone help me what options I need to set to enable this to be viewed?

```
import pandas as pd
list2loop =['a','b','c','d']


for each_item in list2loop:
    execfile("test_file.py")
```

where 'test_file.py' is:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([each_item])   
df
print 3
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not going to work unless you define a function in `test_file`, which you import in your main program, and then call that function with parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simply using the `%run` magic instead of `execfile` (whatever `execfile` is).

Say you have a file `test.py`:

```
#test.py
print(test_input)
```

Then you can simply do

```
for test_input in (1, 2, 3):
    %run -i test.py
```

The `-i` tells Python to run the file in IPython's name space, thus the script knows about all your variables, and variables defined in your script are in your name space afterwards. If you explicitly call `sys.exit` in your script, you have to additionally use `-e`.